# Check if an ODBC DSN is connected or not in C#

Tags: c#, odbc

1. I have a program written in C and makes an ODBC connection to an Oracle DB.
2. I use the .exe file of the C program inside a C# UI.

My Question: Is there anyway in C# to check if there is an open ODBC connection using only DSN string? I know the methods like:

```
    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn = new ystem.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(sConnString);

    if (conn.State==ConnectionState.Open){...}
```

But such methods require establishing the ODBC connection from C# itself (where in my case, the C code (.exe file) establishes the ODBC connection).

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  Checking if there is an open ODBC connection established via a DSN in a different process is unlikely to be possible and is of course a different thing from establishing your own connection.

Comment: @AlexK.
In the User Interface (C#), I want to enable the user to see if the ODBC connection (C) is open or close by using some green/red icons.